# How to access/set other user's environment variables after setregid() and setreuid() in C

Tags: linux, environment-variables, c, setuid, setgid

I have a privileged C program that is executed by a standard user (say `stduser`) and on execution switches to a system user (say `sysuser`) as follows. Basically, I am trying to do something similar to what `sudo -u sysuser env` would do.

envtest.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<shadow.h>
#include<pwd.h>

int main(void){
  struct passwd*pw;
  uid_t sysuid;
  gid_t sysgid;
  char err_module_name[256] = "";

  pw = getpwnam ("ayauser");
  endpwent();

  if (!pw){ //user doesn't really exist
          perror("getpwnam()");
          return errno;
  }

  sysuid = pw->pw_uid;
  sysgid = pw->pw_gid;

  (strcpy(err_module_name, "setregid()") == NULL || setregid(sysgid, sysgid) == 0) &&
  (strcpy(err_module_name, "setreuid()") == NULL || setreuid(sysuid, sysuid) == 0) &&
  (strcpy(err_module_name, "execl()")  == NULL || execl("/usr/bin/env", "/usr/bin/env", NULL) == 0);

  perror(err_module_name);

  return errno;

}
```

I have done:

```
$ sudo chgrp root envtest
$ sudo chown root envtest
$ chmod 6555 envtest
```

After that, when I run the `envtest` program, it shows the same environment variables of `stduser` not `sysuser`. i.e, the output of `env` command and `envtest` command is the same. Where as I am expecting the output should be same as `sudo -u sysuser env`.

What is missing in the code? How can I modify the program to have the same environment variables, that is  set for the `sysuser` ?

Answer (score 1):

What `sudo -i` does, is :

> `-i, --login`
>
> Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell.  This means that login-specific resource files such as `.profile` or `.login` will be read by the shell.

That last point is important, shells read a number of startup files (depending on how exactly they're started, see e.g. [Bash's manual on this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)). Your program doesn't read those files, so it doesn't see the variable assignments in them.

Comment: I understand the point you are trying to make... It means when I do `sudo -u sysuser <some_cmd>` it loads the shell of `sysuser` which sets up the environment, am I right? Still, could you be more specific on how can I do thet in my code? Consider this, `sudo` is a privilleged program, so is my `envtest`. `sudo -u sysuser env` before `exec()`ing `env`,  does some pre-exec activity which causes env to think sysuser triggered it. but in fact it is not... What pre-exec ateps shouid I follow before exec() other than setregid() and setreuid() to see the ssame behaviour as sudo?

Comment: @Anirban, it's not about any pre-exec activity, it's about _what_ is exec'd. `sudo -i` launches a shell, while your program launches `env` directly. You could exec the equivalent of running `bash -l -c /usr/bin/env"` (something like `execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-l" "-c", "/usr/bin/env", NULL)` off the top of my head) to run the shell in the middle. Though `sudo` _does_  also clean up the environment too, there's a bunch of options in `sudoers` for that (`env_reset`, `env_keep`, maybe others). To reproduce those, edit the environment you pass to exec (explicitly or implicitly).